# How to access http headers for Spring Data auditing in WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to make use of http headers to audit my Spring Repository, as mentioned here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing.reactive-auditor-aware

But the challenge I face is that I don't use Spring Security, my userId comes in as plain text in http header.

I got as far as working out that in WebFlux case I need to use Reactor Context, and if I understand it correctly there already is a filter that does it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/reactive/ServerWebExchangeContextFilter.html, but I struggle to write the code to extract it.

Does any one know of any articles/blogs/snippets that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hello Anton.

If i understand your problem correctly, you try having access for header value in controller methods?

Comment: @zdadco that is much easier. I'm trying to implement ReactiveAuditorAware to read the headers and pass the into to @ CreatedBy annotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
// get the request
HttpServletRequest request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
// get headers
username = request.getHeader("x-username");
```

I'm not sure if WebFlux can work

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution does **not work** with Spring WebFlux.

You can read about that [here](https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-01/webflux-get-request-anywhere/#gsc.tab=0).